# PowerShell Tee to console in a pipeline

Tags: powershell

I generate a csv file :

```
myscript.ps1 | Export-Csv result.csv
```

but it's a slow process and I'd like to see progress. I thought Tee-Object would do it but I'm looking for a 'Tee to console' effect which Tee-Object doesn't seem to offer?

If I do

```
myscript.ps1 | Write-Host | Export-Csv result.csv
```

that destroys the objects. How can I Tee-Host ?

Comment: In short, as of PowerShell 7+ `Tee-Object` actually is able to output to the console, by using the special file names `CON` (Windows) or `/dev/tty` on *nix systems.

Comment: Applied to your case: `myscript.ps1 | tee CON | Export-Csv result.csv`

Comment: alas I have to stay with PS5.1 since that's what's on my colleagues' desktops

Comment: The linked duplicate also shows ways to do this in PS5.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mathias has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73416121/14722232) exactly what you asked, but as an alternative I'd suggest using `write-progress` as a way of getting a visual indication of how a task is progressing.

Comment: to be fair, you did answer what I said I wanted — a progress report :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `ForEach-Object`:

```
myscript.ps1 |ForEach-Object { $_ |Out-Host; $_ } |Export-Csv ...
```

Comment: This is tempting, but applying `Out-Host` to _individual_ objects will result in unexpected table formatting, as each object will be in its own table, with its own header. Try `$result = Get-ChildItem / | % { $_ | Out-Host; $_ }`
To solve that problem, a proxy function is needed. However, in PowerShell (Core) 7+ you can simply pipe to `Tee-Object ($IsWindows ? 'CON' : '/dev/tty')`